# How to copy from pointer to structure in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am using a C DLL from my VB.NET program. The C function has a callback which sends a pointer to a large, complex structure.

```
typedef int (CALLBACK *fAnalyzerDataCallBack)(
    LLONG lAnalyzerHandle, DWORD dwAlarmType, void* pAlarmInfo, BYTE *pBuffer,
    DWORD dwBufSize, LDWORD dwUser, int nSequence, void *reserved );
```

The AlarmInfo points to different structures based on the value of dwAlarmType. I defined the structure but am stuck at that point. I tried

```
Marshal.PtrToStructure(Of DEV_EVENT_FACERECOGNITION_INFO)(AlarmInfo, structFaceRecognitionInfo)
```

but that doesn't work as the PtrToStructure requires a class in the second parameter.

If pertinent, I am pasting part of the structure definition here:

```
   <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
    Public Structure DEV_EVENT_FACERECOGNITION_INFO
        Public nChannelID As Int16 ' ChannelId
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=128)>
        Public szName() As Byte '[128] Event name
        Public nEventID As Int16 ' Event ID
        Public UTC As NET_TIME ' the Event happen time
        Public stuObject As DH_MSG_OBJECT ' have being detected Object
        Public nCandidateNum As Int16 ' candidate number
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=50)>
        Public stuCandidates() As CANDIDATE_INFO      '50 [DH_MAX_CANDIDATE_NUM]; // candidate info
<<SNIP>>
        Public stuCustomProjects As NET_CUSTOM_PROJECTS_INFO ' Face recognition project customization information
        Public bIsDuplicateRemove As Boolean ' Smart retail, whether it conforms To the de duplication strategy (True: conforms to false: does Not conform to)
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=4)>
        Public byReserved24() As Byte '[4] Byte alaignment
    End Structure
```

So, how do I copy from the pointer into my structure?

This is a 3rd party DLL and the source is not available.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error you get when you try this?  I just tried what I think is equivalent code, and it builds without error.

Comment: No error at compile time. Runtime gives an error. I managed to solve this using: ''''structFaceRecognitionInfo = CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(AlarmInfo, GetType(DEV_EVENT_FACERECOGNITION_INFO)), DEV_EVENT_FACERECOGNITION_INFO)''''